# Swift array element map

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have array `[[one, two, three, four]]` and I want to convert array in `[["one", "two"," three", "four"]]` without using a loop in Swift 3.

I tried

```
let myArray = array.map { String($0) }
```

But this is returning `["[one, two, three, four]"]`.

Comment: https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/array-in-swift.html

Comment: are you using nested array or array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you actually have two arrays.  You have an array OF arrays of whatever one, etc. are.

Try:

```
let result = array.map { $0.map { String($0) } }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array([[one, two, three, four]][0].map({String($0)}))`